# Variable in sub using data on dynamic userform - Error 438 " object doesn't support this property

Tags: excel, dynamic, userform, vba

I am creating dynamically a userform where the number of comboboxes and textboxes are variable. Then I want to dispatch this data into different sheets.

To do so, I want to avoid the `.Insertlines xx, "blabla"` to code the userform so I call a sub in the module when the button is click. As the number of combobox and textbox is variable I got a For...Next loop to deal with it.

My problem is I can't figure out how to get the value on the userform [User form: UF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzYyV.jpg)

Here is the beginning of my code in the module to create the userform (I don't put everything, it is just to show the context:

- UF2 is declared as public
- UF2 is SET in a public sub

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Public Nb As Integer 'Number of people for creating UF2 form
  Public Datbox As Date 'Date for record
  Public UF2 As Object 'Forms for operator time
  Public PckF As Object 'Form for number of operators/workstation
  Public WC As String 'memory which workcenter ticked


  Public Sub Packing()
  ```

  ' MANY LINES OF DIM FURTHER

  ```
  'Adatable name list for combobox
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employees").Select
  ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
  Lstdata = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Address
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Commands").Select

  'Packing record userform creation
  Set UF2 = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3) 'global form
      With UF2
      .Properties("Caption") = "Packing record"
      .Properties("Width") = "250"
      .Properties("Height") = "110"
      .Properties("Height") = .Properties("Height") + Nb * 25
      End With

  Set CB2650 = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.Checkbox.1")
      With CB2650
          .Top = 0
          .Left = 10
          .Width = 50
          .Height = 30
          .Caption = "Liners (2650)"
          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
      End With
  ```

And so on, and so on...

My Problem is situated here, when I click on "Pack" button it is calling this Sub

```
    Public Sub SavePack()

Dim e, F As Integer
Dim OP, OPh, Pkbin As String 'OP=operator name, OPh= hours value, Pkbin=Number of bins packed

For e = 1 To Nb

    OP = UF2.Controls("ComboBox" & e).value
    OPh = UF2.Controls("TextBox" & e).value

'Checking value of variables (WIP)
    MsgBox ("OP value is " & OP)
    MsgBox ("oph value is " & OPh)


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Team sheet record")
        .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = OP
        .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2).value = OPh
        .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).value = Datbox
        .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4).value = WC
    End With
```

BOOM!! Error 438 on `OP= UF2.Controls("ComboBox" & e).value`

I tried many different things and the closest was:
`UserForm2.Controls("ComboBox" & e).value` (No error - because the userform is named like this, when created) but the value returned is empty.

Do you have any hint/ideas?
Thank you.

PS: I used UF2.something else.value but it returned an "Error 424 - Object required" while it is already set up with "With...End With"

Comment: Is the module which contains this code a standard module or the module which contains the event handlers for the userform or something else?

Comment: Not sure to understand, let me try to answer: It is a normal module (not class module) it is the same module where are written `Option Explicit`, the `Set` function and the `Public Sub SavePack()`

Comment: Hi! it's been a month now and I am still stuck! it is driving me insane. I start thinking I should go back to the original idea (but waayyyyyy longer) which is to use `.Insertlines` command when the form is created...